# How to create string with multiple spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace, space, html-entities

By creating a variable

```
var a = 'something' + '        ' + 'something'
```

I get this value: `'something something'`.

How can I create a string with multiple spaces on it in JavaScript?

Comment: use `\xa0` code for each ` ` space

Comment: also can use `&nbsp;` in html

Answer (score 159, accepted):

**In 2022** - use ES6 **[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** for this task.
If you need [IE11 Support](https://caniuse.com/template-literals) - use a [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/).

```
let a = `something       something`;
```

**Template Literals** are fast, powerful, and produce cleaner code.

---

If you *need* IE11 support and you don't have [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/), stay strong  and use `\xa0` - it is a *NO-BREAK SPACE* char.

Reference from [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex), you can write as below:

```
var a = 'something' + '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0' + 'something';
```

Comment: Nice! When you add it to an html element jQuery converts \xa0 to &nbsp;

Comment: Thanks. This worked to pad a curved span around a Dance Style being input elsewhere:
$('#DanceStyle').text("\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0" + $('#Dances_Moderated_DanceStyle').val() + "\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0")

Comment: Thanks! 
that's also very helpful when you need an invisible char when you have to provide some value but you actually only add a space.

Answer (score 25):

in ES6:

```
let a = 'something' + ' '.repeat(10) + 'something'
```

old answer:

```
var a = 'something' + Array(10).fill('\xa0').join('') + 'something'
```

number inside `Array(10)` can be changed to needed number of spaces

Answer (score 17):

Use `&nbsp;`

It is the entity used to represent a non-breaking space. It is essentially a standard space, the primary difference being that a browser should not break (or wrap) a line of text at the point that this   occupies.

```
var a = 'something' + '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp' + 'something'
```

### Non-breaking Space

A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space (&nbsp;).

Remember that browsers will always truncate spaces in HTML pages. If you write 10 spaces in
your text, the browser will remove 9 of them. To add real spaces to your text, 
you can use the **&nbsp;**
character entity.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Demo

```js
var a = 'something' + '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp' + 'something';

document.body.innerHTML = a;
```

Answer (score 4):

With template literals, you can use multiple spaces or multi-line strings and string interpolation. Template Literals are a new ES2015 / ES6 feature that allows you to work with strings. The syntax is very simple, just use backticks instead of single or double quotes:

```js
let a = `something                 something`;
```

and to make multiline strings just press enter to create a new line, with no special characters:

```
let a = `something 

    
                         something`;
```

The results are exactly the same as you write in the string.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6 you can build strings like this:

```
const a = `something ${'\xa0'.repeat(10)} something`
```

Just add any space between ` ` and print variables inside with ${var}

Comment: Please provide some text description when answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<pre>` tag with innerHTML. The HTML `<pre>` element represents preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file. The text is typically rendered using a non-proportional ("monospace") font. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as written. If you don't want a different font, simply add `pre` as a selector in your CSS file and style it as desired.

Ex:

```
var a = '<pre>something        something</pre>';
document.body.innerHTML = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this problem with the string variable itself, but only when the string is converted into html.

One can use `replace` and a regex to translate spaces into protected spaces `replace(/ /g, '\xa0')`.

```js
var a = 'something' + '        ' + 'something'

p1.innerHTML = a
p2.innerHTML = a.replace(/ /g, '\xa0')
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

BTW, if you input many spaces into `contenteditable`, they are translated as alternating sequences of spaces and protected spaces as you can try here:

```html
<p contenteditable onkeyup="result.value = this.innerHTML">put many space into this editable paragraph and see the results in the textarea</p>

<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```